# subtract time between two values set in localstorage

Tags: javascript, storage

I have a quiz program written in vanilla JS. It is supposed to log the time it takes to complete it.

What I would like to achieve is how long it takes for the user to answer the questions by subtraction two variables (strings). If it is even possible.

When the user has stated his name and presses a button "STart Quiz" the currrent time is logged in localstorage like so:

```
var storeName;
var d = new Date();
var h = getHours();
var m = getMinutes();
var s = getSeconds();
var startTime = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
var endTime = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
var result;

var storage = {
    storeName: storeName,
    startTime: startTime,
    endTime: null,
    result: result
};
```

The tricky part is I do not know how to subtract startTime from EndTime to get the time it took to answer the questions. This quiz is over in minutes, so to use the hour is redundant.

When the user has clicked "submit" answer on the last question I want the time logged in LS as endTime.

I hope I have not been unclear and thank you all in advance very much for your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing string as date, directly store the time in milliseconds. Then you can subtract the start time with end time to figure out the time difference.

```
var startTime = Date.now();
var storage = {
    storeName: storeName,
    startTime: startTime,
    endTime: null,
    result: result
};
```

Later you can calculate the endTime using `Date.now()` and subtract that from startTime to get the time difference.

```
storage.endTime = Date.now();

//difference
var diff = storage.endTime - storage.startTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You use your new Date() wrong.
Should be this.

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var s = d.getSeconds();
console.log(h);
```

As for futher implementation you should save current time then use timer on click/login. After that substract these two values. Example for seconds. You just devide (and/or take a modulo to go to real minutes at current time) by for example 3600 to get seconds instead of an hour. Or you can use all your variable and subtract the time. On the way if you get problems with addition for example you can get 5 + 3 = 53 instead of 8 you use Number(5) + Number(3) to do adition instead of concat. Good luck :P

EDIT: also to get time from your string. With split you get array of value.

```
var test = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
console.log(test.split(":"));
```

Comment: Thanks for such a speedy reply PVL. I will try this. Thank you.